# Setting up presto for custom s3 using hive metastore

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3, hive

I have never worked with presto or hive before. And I am getting pretty confused here about setting up presto with hive connector for a custom s3 service. Here are the steps I performed:

- Installed Presto
- Installed Hive
- Set up valued in `hive-site.xml`
- Configured hive.properties for custom s3 url as followed:

```
connector.name = hadoop-hive2
hive.metastore.uri = thrift://localhost:9083
hive.non-managed-table-writes-enabled = true
hive.s3.ssl.enabled = false
hive.s3.max-connections = 500
hive.s3.multipart.min-file-size = 20 MB
hive.s3.multipart.min-part-size = 10 MB
hive.s3.endpoint = http://endpoint.com
hive.s3.path-style-access = true
hive.s3.aws-access-key = AKEY
hive.s3.aws-secret-key = SKEY
```

But I am not able to understand if it is required to setup the `presto.s3.credentials-provider` class. And if yes, how? Is there any sample code for this? All I want to do is read a bucket from on-prem s3 url that has a `path-style-access` and query using presto?

Is the setup I have done is enough, because when I try to run `hive --service metastore` I do not see anything output and all it says `starting hive metastore`. How do I set up a successful connection between presto and custom s3?